# How to compare state or get data from state or use state of flutter bloc cubit?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm new to flutter BloC and I'm confused about its state usage. From the counter app, I built another basic app to show a different widget based on its state. But not sure how to do that.

Cubits:

```
part 'home_bloc_state.dart';

class HomeBlocCubit extends Cubit<HomeBlocState> {
  HomeBlocCubit() : super(HomeBlocInitial());


  void showHome() {
    emit(HomeBlocInitial());
  }

  void showStudents() {
    emit(HomeBlocStudents());
  }


}
```

//state

```
part of 'home_bloc_cubit.dart';


@immutable
abstract class HomeBlocState {}

class HomeBlocInitial extends HomeBlocState {}
class HomeBlocStudents extends HomeBlocState {}
```

With a button widget I can add/toggle events:

```
final myBloc = BlocProvider.of<HomeBlocCubit>(context);

 return Container(
  child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () { 
          myBloc.showHome(); 
        }, 
        child: Text('Home'),
      ), )
```

To show events on UI I would like to return a Text widget based on state.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Align(child:
        BlocBuilder<HomeBlocCubit, HomeBlocState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              //do something based on state.
              //How to check or compare or get data from this state?
              switch (state) {
                case   HomeBlocState: //error, - how to use?
                  break;
              }
      return Text(
        "Welcome to this page: " + state.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 60 ),
      );
    })));
  }
```

How to show UI based on state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Dart 3 you may leverage pattern matching and sealed classes. Now it is possible to change `state` like that:

```dart
sealed class HomeBlocState {}
class HomeBlocInitial extends HomeBlocState {}
class HomeBlocStudents extends HomeBlocState {}
```

and use pattern matching in the builder:

```dart
return switch(state) {
  HomeBlocInitial() => LoadingView(),
  HomeBlocStudents() => StudentsList(),
};
```

---

#### old answer

You may check whether `state` is in a required state by calling

```dart
if (state is HomeBlocInitial) {
  ...
}
```

If you prefer switches:

```dart
switch (state.runtimeType) {
  case HomeBlocInitial:
    return const HomeInitial();
  default:
    // probably throw
    return const SizedBox();
}
```

A more mature approach (if you're good with code generation) would be to use [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for states.
In that case, your state would be declared as:

```dart
@freezed
class HomeBlocState with _$Failfast{
  const factory HomeBlocState.initial() = _Initial;
  const factory HomeBlocState.students() = _Students;
}
```

And inside `BlocBuilder` you'll have:

```dart
return state.map(
  initial: (initialState) => ...,
  students: (studentsState) => ...,
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The approach works. But is this check possible with `switch` statement?

Comment: yeap, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @olexa.le why can't we check the state like `if(state is HomeBlocState.students())` ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: `HomeBlocState.students()` returns an object, and it is not a valid thing to compare an object instance with a type with `is`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```dart
if(state is HomeBlocInitial){
  return MyInitWidget();
} else if( state is HomeBlocStudents){
  return StudentsWidget();
} else {
  return SomethingWentWrongWidget();
}
```

For a good example check this out: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/recipesfluttershowsnackbar?id=ui-layer